# Magento 2 filter customer collection by website id wise in admin grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid

Actually I have requirement to create a Dealer module. I have create it but when dealer login in to admin section. At that time only those customer should display who is created from that specific dealer website. I have manage dealer as different-different website.

Please help me if any one has overwrite admin customer grid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have did this functionality in one of my project.
To overwrite customer grid you need to overwrite UI component.

First of all create **etc/di.xml** in your module with below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider" type="Your\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Customer\DataProvider" />
</config>
```

I have tried to extend Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider in my Customer\DataProvider file but it was creating issue to get customer collection filter with "website_id". So, I have implement main interface file. And used all functions of interface file.

Create **Your\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Customer\DataProvider.php** file with below code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Your\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AttributeMetadataInterface;

class DataProvider implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface
{    
    /**
     * @var AttributeRepository
     */
    private $attributeRepository;
    protected $_authSession;

     /**
     * Data Provider name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Data Provider Primary Identifier name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryFieldName;

    /**
     * Data Provider Request Parameter Identifier name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $requestFieldName;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * Provider configuration data
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * @var ReportingInterface
     */
    protected $reporting;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteria
     */
    protected $searchCriteria;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param Reporting $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param AttributeRepository $attributeRepository
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        \Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
        $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
        $this->reporting = $reporting;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->_authSession = $authSession;        
        $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
    {
        if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
            if ('*' == $paramValue) {
                $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
            }

            if ($paramValue) {
                $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                    '%s%s/%s/',
                    $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                    $paramName,
                    $paramValue
                );
                $this->addFilter(
                    $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Data Provider name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get primary field name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrimaryFieldName()
    {
        return $this->primaryFieldName;
    }

    /**
     * Get field name in request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRequestFieldName()
    {
        return $this->requestFieldName;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMeta()
    {
        return $this->meta;
    }

    /**
     * Get field Set meta info
     *
     * @param string $fieldSetName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFieldSetMetaInfo($fieldSetName)
    {
        return isset($this->meta[$fieldSetName]) ? $this->meta[$fieldSetName] : [];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $fieldSetName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFieldsMetaInfo($fieldSetName)
    {
        return isset($this->meta[$fieldSetName]['children']) ? $this->meta[$fieldSetName]['children'] : [];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $fieldSetName
     * @param string $fieldName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFieldMetaInfo($fieldSetName, $fieldName)
    {
        return isset($this->meta[$fieldSetName]['children'][$fieldName])
            ? $this->meta[$fieldSetName]['children'][$fieldName]
            : [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {           
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter);
    }

    /**
     * self::setOrder() alias
     *
     * @param string $field
     * @param string $direction
     * @return void
     */
    public function addOrder($field, $direction)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($field, $direction);
    }

    /**
     * Set Query limit
     *
     * @param int $offset
     * @param int $size
     * @return void
     */
    public function setLimit($offset, $size)
    {
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setPageSize($size);
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage($offset);
    }

    /**
     * @param SearchResultInterface $searchResult
     * @return array
     */
    protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $arrItems = [];

        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
        }

        $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();

        return $arrItems;
    }

    /**
     * Returns search criteria
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        if (!$this->searchCriteria) {
            $this->searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
            $this->searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->name);
        }
        return $this->searchCriteria;
    }    

    /**
     * Get config data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfigData()
    {
        return isset($this->data['config']) ? $this->data['config'] : [];
    }

    /**
     * Set data
     *
     * @param mixed $config
     * @return void
     */
    public function setConfigData($config)
    {
        $this->data['config'] = $config;
    }

    /**
     * Returns Search result
     *
     * @return SearchResultInterface
     */
    public function getSearchResult()
    {
        return $this->reporting->search($this->getSearchCriteria());
    }



    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {                
        $user = $this->_authSession->getUser();  

        /// I have get "website_id" from user custom attribute $user->getWebsiteRestrictions() you can get current website id

        if($user->getWebsiteRestrictions() != 0){  

        /// Called "website_id" filter functionality.

            $this->addFilter(
                $this->filterBuilder->setField('website_id')->setValue($user->getWebsiteRestrictions())->setConditionType('eq')->create()
            );          
        }

        $data = $this->searchResultToOutput($this->getSearchResult());    
            foreach ($this->attributeRepository->getList() as $attributeCode => $attributeData) {
                foreach ($data['items'] as &$item) {
                    if (isset($item[$attributeCode]) && !empty($attributeData[AttributeMetadataInterface::OPTIONS])) {
                        if(is_array($item[$attributeCode])){
                            $item[$attributeCode] = $item[$attributeCode];                            
                        }else{
                            $item[$attributeCode] = explode(',', $item[$attributeCode]);    
                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }     
          return $data;                  
    }
}
```

When customer grid call at that time getData() function call. In that function I have added custom code to filter collection "website_id" wise.please check getData() function and make changes as per your requirement. Above code will filer customer website_id wise.

Thanks.